# How do you solve $\left( \frac{3^{2020}+5^{2020}+7^{2020}}{3} \right)^{2020}\mod 8 $

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

is the answer simple, i look it up on wolfram alpha and i get complex result..

Comment: Tip: two $\$ $ could replace the pair "[math] [/math]".

Comment: $3^2\equiv1$, $5^2\equiv1$, $7^2\equiv1$ mod $8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more pedestrian answer, that ignores the knowledge of the ring $\Bbb Z/8$ and the fact that division with $3$ is allowed in it, and of the ring/field $\Bbb Z/3=\Bbb F_3$.

We have
$$
3^{2020} +
5^{2020} +
7^{2020} 
\\
=
9^{1010} +
25^{1010} +
49^{1010} \\
=
(8+1)^{1010} +
(3\cdot 8+1)^{1010} +
(6\cdot 8+1)^{1010} 
\ .
$$
Now we imaginary open the parentheses, getting only terms. All but one of the terms for each parenthesis are not divisible by $8$, these are $1^{1010}$, and $1^{1010}$, and $1^{1010}$.
So the result is giving the rest $3$ modulo eight.

On the other hand, the first parenthesis is a power of $3$, thus divisible by $3$, and in $(3\cdot 8+1)^{1010}$,
$(6\cdot 8+1)^{1010} $
only the terms $1^{1010}$, and $1^{1010}$ are not divisible by $3$.

So the number 
$$
3^{2020} +
5^{2020} +
7^{2020}
$$
has the rest $2$ when divided by three. The big expression 
$$
\left( \frac{3^{2020}+5^{2020}+7^{2020}}{3} \right)
$$
ist thus a rational number with denominator $3$, which is irreducible.
Taking the whole at power $2020$ introduces the denominator
$3^{2020}$, and it cannot be taken modulo eight, this operation does not make any sense (without giving one to it).

---

Note: If we know how to work in $\Bbb F_3$, then in this field
$$
3^{2020} +
5^{2020} +
7^{2020}
=
0^{2020} +
(-1)^{2020} +
1^{2020}
=
0+1+1\ .
$$

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure $5^{2020} + 7^{2020}$ is divisible by $3$? In my knowledge, it's not.

Comment: That's not an answer

Comment: This is my answer. I say the problem is invalid because the left hand side is not an integer.

Comment: Yep. That makes it a comment and not an answer.

Comment: ahh, okay, thanks for the comment/answer

Answer (score -1):

Note that $3^2 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 7^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, so your expression simplifies to $\left ( \frac{1^{1010}+1^{1010}+1^{1010}}{3} \right )^{2020} \equiv 1^{2020} \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: The left hand side of the congruence is not an integer.

Comment: @Servaes fyi: $\bmod 8\!:\,\  n/3 :=  3^{-1}n\equiv 3n\ \ $

Comment: @Servaes It doesn't matter whether or not the LHS is an integer as division is the same as multiplication by the multiplicative inverse of the denominator, which exists as long as the denominator and the modulus are co-prime.